# AVL tree vs Binary Search in an array(only for searching & no insertion or deletion) when number of elementsto be stored is known in advance

Tags: search, data-structures

Any reason why i should be using AVL tree as opposed to using binary search in an array, when i know the number of elements to be stored in advance and is of fixed size.Also only the search operation is to be performed??
Is there Any other data structure or algo which is better than them both for the search purpose??

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your binary search solution will perform better if you are storing the array in contiguous memory chunk and the AVL tree would use a sparse collection of node objects which would yield poor spatial cache locality.

Depending on the type of data, you can use interpolation search would which provide `O(loglogn)` performance - though this would increase your worst case time complexity to `O(n)`. This is used if the data is following  a distribution that is uniform, so you would base the guess index not on the middle but rather the *expected* position. Another option would be to have hash table which is normally `O(1)` get, which with Cuckoo hashing would guarantee `O(1)` if created properly regardless of collisions.